For which n is p(n)# + 1 prime?

The primorial $\color{blue}{p_{11}\text{#} = 200560490130}$, and $\color{blue}{p_{11}\text{#} + 1 = 200560490131}$ is prime.  There are other times when $\color{blue}{p_{n}\text{#} + 1}$ is not prime; for example, $\color{blue}{p_{6}\text{#} + 1 = 30031}$ is not prime.
For which positive integers $n$ is  $\color{blue}{p_{n}\text{#} + 1}$  prime?   Also, are there infinitely many such $n$ ?


See Wikipedia's Primorial prime article. As it states there, the OEIS A014545 page shows additional values. Note the Wikipedia article also states "As of $2022$, the largest known prime of the form $p_n# + 1$ is $392113# + 1 (n = 33\text{,}237)$ with $169\text{,}966$ digits, found in $2001$ by Daniel Heuer".

It is not known how many there are. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimorialPrime.html

Unsolved problem (according to Wikipedia): Are there an infinite number of prime Euclid numbers?

See here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45742/are-there-an-infinite-number-of-prime-euclid-numbers?_gl=11ugml61_gaMTI3MjIwOTEyMi4xNzEyOTQxMjY0_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTcxMzA0MTc4Ny41LjEuMTcxMzA0OTAzNS4wLjAuMA..#comment109952_45742
